# How to scroll table view with toolbar at the top of the view

Tags: iphone

I have a view with a toolbar at the top and a table view with text fields in it's cells. When I want to edit the text fields placed in the bottom of the table view the keyboard is hiding the text field being edited (as the table view is not scrolled up). 
I tried to implement http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html but this makes my whole view move up (the toolbar and the table view) while I would like to have the toobar at the top of the view for the whole time. 
I modified the mentioned code to something like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

CGRect textFieldRect = [tableView.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
CGRect viewRect = [tableView.window convertRect:tmpTableView.bounds fromView:tableView];

CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;

if (heightFraction < 0.0)  {
    heightFraction = 0.0;
} else if (heightFraction > 1.0) {
    heightFraction = 1.0;
}

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
} else  {
    animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
}

CGRect viewFrame = tableView.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[tableView setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

and

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
CGRect viewFrame = tableView.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

[tableView setFrame:viewFrame];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This made my toolbar stay at the top, but unfortunately the table view overlays the toolbar and the toolbar is not visible.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repositioning the table view, you should resize it so that the keyboard does not overlap it.

Comment: But I want to scroll the table view to have the text field being edited above the keyboard. Is the sam behavaiour possible with simple resize of the table view?

Comment: After you have resized it, you can scroll any cell into the visible area with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`.

Comment: What is the use of resizing then if I could scroll any cell into visible area? I could scrool even when the table view is normal size, right?  
btw. I cannot make   
scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: work. I tried simply:
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
[self.settingsTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

to scroll the second cell from the second row (just to see if it works), which is hidden under the keyboard.